# Attributed String with String interpolation does not work(swift)

Tags: swift, string, string-interpolation

I want to use an attributed string in string interpolation. but it works as it appears in the screenshot. the attributed string is not formatted the right way. why does this happen? Is there an alternative way to overcome this problem?

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var denemeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        var nameString: String = "any String"
            denemeLabel.text = ""

            let nameAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 18)]
            let attributedNameString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: nameString, attributes: nameAttribute)

            let nsAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(attributedNameString) another String")
            denemeLabel.attributedText = nsAttributedString

    }
```

Comment: //let nsAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(attributedNameString)");denemeLabel.attributedText = attributedNameString

Comment: What do you mean by `the attributed string is not formatted the right way` ? If you want to set the attributed string in your label then just do this `denemeLabel.attributedText = attributedNameString`

Comment: @Torongo you can see what I'm talking about by looking at the picture. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWGwa.png)

Comment: Is `denemeLabel.attributedText = attributedNameString` solve your problem? If not please provide the expected output format.

Comment: @Torongo actually I want to concatenate with another string. I updated my code block according to my request. Updated part is (string:"\(attributedNameString) another String")

Comment: you can affect bunch of key to an AttributeString  see this link for more information : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Xcode 10.1 Swift 4.2**

```
var nameString: String = "any String"

// Set Attributes for the first part of your string
let att1 = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 18.0)]

// Set Attributes for the second part of your string
let att2 = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)]

// Create the first part of your attributed string
let attributedString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: nameString, attributes: att1)

// Create the second part of your attributed string
let attributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "another String", attributes: att2)

// Append the second string to the end of the first string
attributedString1.append(attributedString2)

// Update your label
denemeLabel.attributedText = attributedString1
```

[image]